# What to do about infrequent (seemingly) random JavaScript errors in production?

Tags: javascript, debugging, production-environment

I'm going to come clean and admit that out of sheer ignorance I've been flying blind with my websites until recently when I deployed a site with [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) (an error logging facility for ASP.NET) and a controller on the server to send all uncaught JavaScript exceptions. This was an eyeopening experience to say the least.

One of my sites is getting about 150-200 visitors a day. About once a day I get an Elmah JavaScript stacktrace similar to this one:

```
CCS.Exceptions.JavaScriptException: Unspecified error.: at document path
    'http://www.*******.com/*****'. at anonymous('Unspecified error.',
    'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js', '5')
    at anonymous()
```

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and web development in general so I'd appreciate some advice:

- How should I go about getting to the root cause of problems like this? Any advice for debugging problems in production (specifically JavaScript)?
- Where would you rank this on the scale of importance? I realize that question is almost impossible to answer without knowing everything on my plate. But what I'm hoping for is advice for prioritizing this kind of stuff. Is my hair on fire? Or, "Meh, this is really common and given all of the browsers and OSes these days this kind of thing is bound to happen."

Comment: just visit your site and look at the browser's console to see if there are any errors

Comment: @akonsu Only a small subset of visits are generating said error ("about once a day" over 150-200 daily visitors) - this might be a subset which runs a very particular browser/environment configuration or performs a certain set of actions that cannot be duplicated in a normal test environment.

Comment: I'm going to expose my ignorance and ask: Is it possible to get this from plug-ins running javascript as addons to the browser? The reason I ask is I'm seeing this exception now (after some adjustments to help debug problems): CCS.Exceptions.JavaScriptException: Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object: at document path 'http://www.*****.com/****'.
  at anonymous('Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object', 'miscellaneous_bindings', '58') -- I do not recognize this javascript...

Comment: @akonsu I've attempted to reproduce these problems using each version of the browser reporting the problem and no luck. I did make one change by hosting the jQuery files on my server rather than on Google's CDN and many of the (what I consider) mysterious problems have disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chances are pretty good that each one of these exceptions is a web page that is NOT working as designed.  In order to understand that priority, you need to understand the following:

1. What percentage of page views are being affected?
2. What are the specific exceptions and what trouble do they cause?
3. How important is that trouble to your business.
4. How much time will it take to identify and fix these and how does the business importance of that compare with other projects on your plate?

In general, you won't know the answers to any of these questions without further research so you'll either have to decide that all exceptions that aren't fully understood are a bad thing and should at least be understood.

Or, you'll have to decide to launch an investigative project to get more information related to these questions and then decide whether to fix it or not.

Or, you'll have to decide that you just havne't heard enough reports of problems with your web site to warrant any further investigation (I personally don't like this option because you're guessing that it doesn't matter).

Without knowing much detail about your business, my recommendation would be to budget and plan an investigation project to learn where these errors are coming from and understand their impact on the usability of the site.  Making decisions with some data in hand is way better than guessing.

---

As for debugging, you ultimately need to find out which line of code is triggering the exception.  You also may want to record what browser configuration is generating the error (in case it's a browser version related issue).  You can start by understand what each piece of information in your stacktrace report means and what it tells you and then find out if you can enable more detailed tracking of the exceptions in the Elmah system.  If not and you can figure out approximately where the error's are coming from, you can implement your own exception logging that might be able to capture additional information.

You may also browse through any trouble ticket reports you have on the site because there may be some internal or external reports of problems with the site that might be correlated with these exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript errors can be difficult to get to the bottom of.  The best thing you can do is ensure that your JavaScript is written cleanly and put everything into namespaces to keep your window object as clean as possible and avoid variable hoisting which is a common issue when JavaScript libraries get unruly.  Below is the preferred namespace pattern that I use across the board -

```
/* Namespace pattern */
var myAppNamespace = myAppNamespace || {};
(function(ns) {
    ns.doSomething = function() {
        // enter code here
    };
}(myAppNamespace));

/* Usage */
myAppNamespace.doSomething();
```

Comment: It is working in ~199/200 cases (or much higher). The error generated comes from jQuery and further seems to come from the DOM (perhaps it is in an invalid state). In any case, namespaces, while they do help to create cleaner modules, is a different topic. This question is more hypothetical in how to deal with this rare exception, and what the associated cost/practicality is.

Comment: Are you using any automated minification tools and / or jquery plugins?

Comment: I am not the poster :) However, the jQuery-UI library linked is the minified version ("jquery-ui-.min.js"). That being said, a correct minifier will not alter the semantics of a program.

Comment: They will replace variable names with shortened versions and I have seen in the past variables get hoisted due to automated minification, especially when all is attached to the window object.  Quite possibly not the root cause here, just trying to add some value.

Comment: I am talking more about minification tools, not just the minified version of jquery libraries.  i.e combres or other tools.